# Newbie Issues with Ruby

Tags: ruby

Trying to speed up my airline check in process.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='C:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox 
Developer Edition\firefox.exe'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "https://checkin.westjet.com/"
sleep(1)

first_name = driver.find_element(id: 'firstName')
first_name.click
first_name.send_keys ('Test')

last_name = driver.find_element(id: 'lastName')
last_name.click
last_name.send_keys('Test')

pnr = driver.find_element(id: 'recordLocator')
pnr.click
pnr.send_keys('ABC123')
```

When I run the program, Firefox launches, and I can see the click go into the `firstName` field because the cursor is there, but `send_keys` doesn't put anything into the field. The output from the command prompt shows:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver- 
3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:72:in `assert_ok': status 
code 400 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ServerError)
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:81:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:81:in `create_response'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:104:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:164:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:535:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:365:in `send_keys_to_element'
    from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:154:in `send_keys'
    from C:/Checkin/checkin.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, it's entering fine, Can I give you the code which switch off the geckodriver and switch on the legacy driver? That would work. But that is longing the ESR version of firefox, Can you install that?

Comment: It's working fine for me! Just move Legacy driver and use ESR version of Firefox, it will work.

Comment: Hi Raj, would love to do what you suggest but I'm a complete newb ... would you mind providing a step by step?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First prerequisite to my code to work is, Install FireFox ESR, But before you install, uninstall the existing firefox and delete the profile and then use this code, I have included the select_list code as well for your reference, If you are not in need of that code, please delete it.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(marionette: false)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, desired_capabilities: caps, profile: "default"
driver.navigate.to "https://checkin.westjet.com/"
Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(driver.find_element(:id, "departureCity")).select_by(:text, "ABBOTSFORD, BC (YXX)")
driver.find_element(:id, "firstName").send_keys "Test"
driver.find_element(:id, "lastName").send_keys "Test"
driver.find_element(:id, "recordLocator").send_keys "ABC123"
```